# How to make dependent records inactive but not destroy using concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a model named runningmenu i want to inactive it on destroy but not hard delete, and also i want to inactive all its dependent records e.g orders

i am using ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5 i have tried using active record concerns, on before destroy i am calling concern stop destroy method to flip delete_status and throw abort. when i abort on dependent records it sends failed to destroy exception to runningmenu destroy action. But it just aborted on first record and not make all dependent records inactive.

```
module Deletable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def stop_destroy
    self.deleted!
    throw(:abort)
  end

  def stop_destroy_for_orders
    self.update_column(:status, Order.statuses[:cancelled])
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

ON Orders model i have:

```
before_destroy -> { stop_destroy_for_orders }
```

on runningmenu model i have:

```
has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
before_destroy -> { stop_destroy }
```

expected result is to make all runningmenu dependent childs inactive on delete but not hard delete. But now only first instance status set to cancelled and roll backed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're happy using gems or not, but one of the more popular ones is paranoia:

https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia

```
bin/rails generate migration AddDeletedAtToOrders deleted_at:datetime:index
```

Add the deleted_at column to your orders, then run `rake db:migrate` to add the column to your database. In your orders model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid

  # ...
end
```

Now when you call Order.destroy, the record will not be deleted, but will have its deleted_at column updated with the time of 'deletion'. This will add a default scope to Orders, meaning if you do `Order.all`, it will only return orders with a nil deleted_at. More commands for how to really delete a record and include it in scopes is included in their github above.